# AWS autoscaling deployment setup

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and just realised its extremely complicated, what am trying to achieve is as presented below:

[image]

I have fumbled with this enough and frankly, am close to giving up and going back to my primitive ways. So far I have accomplished the auto scaling and linked them to the load balancer, Now am stuck at obtaining the load balancer IP (Application Load Balancer) so that I can add it to my DNS records. I also have tried Network Load Balancer, and linking it to my ALB (although I don't really like this setup because it has many hops), but still fails, I basically end up with 504 errors, when I try to access through all load balancers, now my huge concern is, without involving Route 53, how do I configure my load balancer (preferrably ALB) to work as in the image above, any help or if anyone can point me towards the direction of solving this I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: You have to provide **exact** details of your ALB, security groups, vpc, route53 and everything else regarding your architecture. Since you haven't provided any relevant info, its difficult to even begin speculating what can be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on the IP of an ALB to access it.
If you need a fixed IP, NLB is a good solution.

You need to debug your solution, and check the links between the components of your app.

In the Target Group of your ALB, verify that the instances are in an `Available` state. Are the SGs correctly setup? Do you indeed have something running on your instances? Is the Health Check successful?

If you provide more details as to where exactly it fails, we can help furhter!

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-find-load-balancer-IP/)  you can get the ip address of the load balancer. But the issue here is the IP addresses for Classic Load Balancers and Application Load Balancers change over time.